# read a file and save it into an object. [No display of loaded data ] in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I know there are a few questions asked about this here is SO.

But I couldn't figure out the solution to my problem from them.

I want to Upload a file into R through shiny and assign it to an object say the object name "Object_name".

I used fileInput in ui.R and did this

```
fileInput('file1', h4('Choose Your Data File'),
                            accept=c('text/csv',
                                     'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain',
                                     '.OUT'))
```

Now I accesses the "file1" and tried to recover my uploaded file through file1$datapath.
I couldn't actually do this. I am getting console errors like....

```
1. Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  'data' argument is of the wrong type
```

And in GUI in the plot plane its showing `Error:'data' argument is of the wrong type`

I have added this piece of code in shinyserver server.R

```
mydata <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    object_name <- read.table(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
  })
```

Is it allowed to access the file directly from the datapath as I am doing above.
Why doesn't it load the uploaded data into "a".

If somebody knows the answer please help me out.

Update:

My dataset is of header = False.
So once I upload the data I have to change the names(my dataset) and then further calculations can be performed.

Considering this code

```
a <- reactive({
   inFile <- input$file1
   if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
   read.table(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
 })
```

Still I cant access the a() [i,e the data I want] and use it into further calculations. I cant assign like `names(a) <- c(.......)` outside reactive because it throws error if I do that ...

```
Error in names(a) <- c("Ei", "Mi", "hours", "Nphy", "Cphy", "CHLphy",  : 
  names() applied to a non-vector
```

And I cant do it inside reactive because I can only assign names once the data "a" or "a()" is ready. so how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `server.r` you need to do `read.csv` (or whatever corresponds to your input file format) to get at the data.  Something like:

```
MyData<-reactive({ read.csv(input$file1$datapath, ...) })
```

Where ... is whatever other arguments that you need for `read.csv()`. Then you can access your data by referring to it as `MyData()`.

**Edit**
If you want to add column names (that aren't in the original .csv) they  you can use the `col.names` argument in `read.csv()`.

Comment: Yeah that may work, but I want to assign the names to all columns so that this dataset is used in further steps of the code. I have added this in my question at the end please check.

Comment: Thanks that worked. again I forgot the col.names and went on to assign through names(my data) <- c(names)...Thanks.