# Load RData into Shiny - data loaded in R workspace but not in Shiny, no errors produced

Tags: r, shiny, rdata

**Objective:** I seek to download a data set (in `.RData` format) I have uploaded on `GitHub` to a `Shiny` app, and use the data set for various plotting purposes.

**Technique:** I am using the `source_data` function from the `repmis` package to load the data into my R session. This loading occurs at the `global.R` file, so I was certain any data loaded would be available to plotting functions in the `server.R` file.

**Problem:** I see the data is loaded in my R workspace if I shift all functions from `global.R` to `server.R` but just before the `shinyServer()` function.
However, **no** data is available to the `Shiny` app, no error is produced, just that nothing is available to plot, or even inspect using `dim()`.

**Similar Questions:** There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654679/loading-a-rdata-file-into-session-but-no-object-loaded-in-shiny), but I haven't obtained any help from this - I am, anyway,  loading data in `Global.R` rather than in `server.R` or `ui.R`.
Another question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25453812/read-a-file-and-save-it-into-an-object-no-display-of-loaded-data-in-shiny-r), but the user reads in data to a reactive source. My data would not be changing, so I am loading it in the `global.R` file.

---

### Global.R

```
#global.R

#-------------------- Loading Libraries ------------------------#   

library(repmis)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(xts)
library(dygraphs)




#-------------------- Loading required data from GitHub Repo -------------------------#

source_data('https://github.com/aliarsalankazmi/SHB_FB_App/raw/master/Data/shbPageData.RData')



#-------------------- Manipulating data for further processing -------------------------#

shb$created_date <- ymd(gsub('T.*', '', shb$created_time))

pageData <- tbl_df(shb) %>%
        arrange(created_date)

byDay <- pageData %>%
        group_by(created_date) %>%
        select(created_date, comments_count, likes_count, shares_count) %>%
        summarise(totalPosts = n(),
              totalLikes = sum(likes_count),
              totalComments = sum(comments_count),
              totalShares = sum(shares_count)) %>%
        arrange(created_date)

#-------------------- Manipulating data for an Overall View  -------------------------#

byDayxts <- as.xts(x = as.matrix(as.data.frame(byDay[,colnames(byDay) != 'created_date'])), order.by = byDay$created_date)
```

### Server.R

```
#server.R

library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)


shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


#---------------------- Plotting for a General Overview --------------------#

    totalOverview <- renderDygraph({
                byDayxts[, colnames(byDayxts) == 'totalPosts'] %>%
                dygraph(main = 'Total Posts per Day Since Beginning', group = 'overall') %>%
                dyAxis('x', drawGrid = FALSE) %>%
                dySeries('totalPosts', label = 'Total Posts') %>%
                dyOptions(includeZero = TRUE, gridLineColor = "lightblue", colors = '#d8b365') %>% 
                dyRangeSelector()
            })    
})
```

### Ui.R

```
#ui.R

library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

    titlePanel(h1("Facebook Data Analysis")),
    tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Graphs",
                fluidRow(
                    column(width = 6, dygraphOutput("totalOverview"))
                    )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
output$totalOverview <- renderDygraph({ ... })
```

not:

```
totalOverview <- renderDygraph({ ... })
```

Comment: ouch, silliest mistake. Thank you.